# C# как найти символ и набор чисел

Tags: c#

подскажите как найти в строке определенный набор чисел и символов, например мне надо найти в строке символ 'P' и пять цифр (пример P12345) символ всегда один и тот же но воцифры разные но всегда одной длины(5) как мне искать этот набор символа и цифр в строке желательно чтоб это работало быстро. Спасибо за ранее

Comment: Регулярные выражения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string str = "P1234567890";
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"P([0-9]{5})");//->{5} - задаете диапазон.
       MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(str);
          if (match.Count > 0)
           {
              foreach (Match m in match)
                  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
           }
```

Ну и `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Comment: `MatchCollection` зачем? Если мач всего один? Чтобы работало быстро, регекс лучше скомпилированный. `if (match.Count > 0)` лишняя проверка. Если их 0, цикл внутри просто ни разу не выполнится. Группа как бы тоже не нужна, вам же не надо число оттуда достать, а если надо, то почему-то не достаете.